# Spring Web-client: Basic Authentication Using Bearer token

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security, spring-webflux

I am trying to to write a web-client where the Bearer token is attached to web-client call like OAUT2 mentioned here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webclient-oauth2

Here is the flow.

First Call to get token:

```
Post:/auth/token
Request Body: form-url-encode ex: name=john&email=john@example.com
Headers: Authorization : Basic "{HardCode TokenHere}"
```

Second to call to external service uisng the token got from above.

```
Service Url:
GET: /service/getUserInfo?email={email}
Headers:
Authorization:Basic {Token Received from first call above}
```

Currently I followed manual approach . I just have the token, i don't have clientId and client secret.

```
@Autowired
WebClient client;

public Mono<String> obtainSecuredResource() {
    Mono<String> resource = client.post()
      .uri("localhost:8085/oauth/token")
      .header("Authorization", "Basic " + {TOKEN_HERE})
      .body(BodyInserters.fromFormData("grant_type", "client_credentials"))
      .retrieve()
      .bodyToMono(JsonNode.class)
      .flatMap(tokenResponse -> {
          String accessTokenValue = tokenResponse.get("access_token")
            .textValue();
          return client.get()
            .uri("localhost:8084/retrieve-resource")
            .headers(h -> h.setBearerAuth(accessTokenValue))
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class);
        });
    return resource.map(res ->
      "Retrieved the resource using a manual approach: " + res);
```

Does spring webflux provides any good way to get token and pass to web-client,like using OAuth2Filter and pass reqgistartionId?

Comment: Try to follow the article to create minimal, reproducible example. It has answers to all your questions. In short, if you configure web client  with authentication filter , `WebClient.builder().filter(oauth)` token will be requested and updated automatically.

Comment: I am good with Oauth2 ,but the solution I am looking for is not OAUT2, it just calls one token api with Baisc token and some payload.

Comment: The solution i am looking for is not oauth2. If you read my question we hit one token api with Baisc Header and request payload and pass that returned token to external service.Like Oauth2 we don't have clientId and clientsecret

Comment: All is oauth2, you need to read up on what oauth2 is. One part of the oauth2 spec is authenticating and getting issued a token. Another part of the specification is to pass the token to a resourse server to access that resoure. So stop saying ”its not oauth2” because it is, please read the rfc so you understand what we are talking about. https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-7

Comment: Updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to use `ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction` that you could customize to satisfy your needs. In this case token will be updated automatically behind the scene.

If you are looking for "manual" approach, you just need to combine 2 requests.

```
public Mono<String> obtainSecuredResource() {
    return getToken()
            .flatMap(token -> getResource(token));
}

private Mono<String> getResource(String authToken) {
        return client.get()
                .uri("localhost:8084/retrieve-resource")
                .headers(h -> h.setBearerAuth(authToken))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class);
}

private Mono<String> getToken() {
        return client.post()
                .uri("localhost:8085/oauth/token")
                .header("Authorization", "Basic " + {TOKEN_HERE})
                .body(BodyInserters.fromFormData("grant_type", "client_credentials"))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(JsonNode.class)
                .map(tokenResponse ->
                    tokenResponse.get("access_token").textValue()
                );
}
```

In this case you will always execute 2 requests and get token for every resource request.

Usually token has expiration and you could save some requests by caching `getToken()` `Mono`.

```
private Mono<String> tokenRequest = getToken().cache(Duration.ofMinutes(30));

public Mono<String> obtainSecuredResource() {
    return tokenRequest
            .flatMap(token -> getResource(token));
}
```

Comment: I am not looking for manual approach. How can I create a bean using ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction which takes Baisc {Token},All the example i have seen has clientId and clientSecret defined in application.properties.Where as, I have only an  encoded token only.

Comment: @Rocky4Ever - did you ever figure out how to do this with Basic auth?

Comment: Yes you can use this https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.12.RELEASE/reference/html/oauth2.html

Comment: @Rocky4Ever Care to elaborate which section? Also only finding clientId and clientSecret examples..

Comment: @nela Did you find how to do this?

Comment: @wbk Yes, You can do something as outline here https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webflux-webclient/client-filter.html.